# How to create a JAR file from gradle that contains the .java fields (source code) as well

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle, build

I am using gradle to build some a uber jar file, this jar file has dependencies and I used this [guide](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/working_with_files.html#sec:creating_uber_jar_example) to create the task that I can run

My task is like this btw I am using kotlin

```
tasks.register<Jar>("uberJar") {
archiveClassifier.set("uber")

from(sourceSets.main.get().output)
duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE;
dependsOn(configurations.runtimeClasspath)
from({
    configurations.runtimeClasspath.get().filter { it.name.endsWith("jar") }.map { zipTree(it) }
}})
```

What can I add to this task to add my .java files as well.

Also I don't really understand much of what is going on here like what actually is SourceSets?

Comment: Not sure this is possible as it's an unusual (if understandable) requirement. You can always add it later with the ``-u`` (update) argument to ``jar``

Comment: This is indeed a very bizarre thing to want to do.

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to accomplish with this JAR?

Comment: I need to have the .java files as well as the .class files in the jar(which I was told is just a renamed zip file)
To submit my work in School
@GreenSaguaro

Comment: @g00se Can you elaborate more on what you mean, is this -u like a additional argument or something to what function? Sorry I am quite new to Gradle typically I use Maven

Comment: The `-u` is an argument to `jar`. See its help. Did you try what was posted as an answer by @GreenSaguaro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this to your `build.gradle.kts` and see if it works:

```kotlin
tasks.named<ProcessResources>("processResources") {
    from("src/main/java")
}
```

When your uber-JAR builds, it should contain the source files. Though this will also add the source files to any JAR. If that is not what you want, then you will need to configure something similar in the uber-JAR setup.

Comment: I used this pretty much I added in the from("src/main/java") and it now includes the .java files.
But I have one more question for this to compile on BlueJ I need the module-info.class file to be removed automatically by gradle. This file is usually in the root of the jar file so is there an exclude() or something cause I tried exclude("src/main/java/module-info.class") and it didn't work

Comment: You would need to exclude module-info.java

Comment: How would you do that? Also I don't think this is one of my files. This is generated automatically when the project is built

Comment: What if you do exclude(“**/module-info.java”)?

Comment: With that added it will still add the module-info.class file to the jar

Comment: Oh …try that same line with .class

Comment: Thanks with this as my task
The code compiles and doesn't include the module-info.class file